# la carga automática en composer no funciona con la función globales

Tags: php, composer

con php 8.1 tengo en mi `composer.json`:

```json
 "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "test.php"
    ]
  }
```

el contenido de `test.php` es:

```php
<?php
namespace /test

function foo(){
    echo 'Hello World';
}
```

en mi `index.php` tengo esto:

```php
<?php
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

foo();
```

pero obtengo `Call to undefined function foo()`

todo lo que se declara como `file` en `autoload` se supone o se espera que se agregue... en este caso esperaba que funcionara como `require_once`, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

***Update***

después de varios intentos; el IDE me sugiere que use esto:

```
use function /foo
```

Esto no era necesario antes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Namespace Global

En PHP, lo que se declara en un archivo sin namespace queda en el espacio global, como pasa con en el típico `helpers.php` que una instalación de Laravel carga implícitamente con (adivinen) funciones helper. Pensemos que su contenido fuera simplemente:

```
<?php

function es_numero($value) {
   return is_numeric($value);
}
```

Desde cualquier otra parte del código yo puedo invocar esa función `es_numero` y PHP sabrá encontrarla en el espacio global aunque me encuentre en otro namespace

```
<?php

namespace App\CualquierCosa;

$foo='1';

// $bar es TRUE
$bar = es_numero($foo);
```

En esto las funciones no se comportan igual que las clases. No porque una clase exista en el espacio  global yo podré llegar y usarla desde otro lado.
Fíjense por ejemplo en `Exception`. Para tirar una excepción necesitas un `use`  statement, o bien usar el Fully Qualified NameSpace:

```
       <?php

       namespace App\CualquierCosa;

       use \LogicException;

       throw new LogicException('...');

       throw new \InvalidArgumentException('...');
```

#### Cuando se necesita `use function` ?

El hecho de poder invocar funciones globales desde cualquier parte no quita que en algunos casos sea necesario un `use` statement. Pensemos por ejemplo el caso en que yo tuviese una declaración local de `es_numero`

```
<?php

namespace App\CualquierCosa;

function es_numero($value) {
   return is_float($value);
}

$foo='1';

// $bar es FALSE
$bar = es_numero($foo);
```

Manda la definición local, porque PHP la encuentra de inmediato y no sigue "buscando aguas arriba" hacia el espacio global.

Para estos casos se puede usar un backslash `\` para aludir explícitamente al espacio global.

```
<?php

namespace App\CualquierCosa;

function es_numero($value) {
   return is_float($value);
}

$foo='1';

// $bar_local es FALSE
$bar_local = es_numero($foo);

// $bar_global es TRUE
$bar_global = \es_numero($foo);
```

De la misma manera yo podría usar esta versión alternativa de `es_numero` desde otro namespace via

```
 <?php

 $bar = es_numero('1'); // TRUE
 $otro_bar = \App\CualquierCosa\es_numero('1'); // FALSE
```

O mediante el statement `use` dejarla como alias local

```
 <?php
 use function App\CualquierCosa\es_numero;

 $bar = es_numero('1'); // FALSE
```

Teniendo además la libertad de rebautizar el alias. Si tuvieras funciones con el mismo nombre esto es incluso mejor para distinguir entre ellas.

```
 <?php

 use function App\CualquierCosa\es_numero as es_float;
 use function es_numero as es_numerico;

 $bar1 = es_float('1'); // FALSE

 $bar2 = es_numerico('1'); // TRUE
```

Es indiferente (pero innecesario y desaconsejado) pasar un leading backslash para usar objetos de otro NS

```
  <?php

  use function \es_numero as es_numerico;
```

#### Nombres válidos

No sólo los namespaces sino [todos los labels en PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) deben consistir en  un underscore o una letra seguido de cualquier cantidad de letras, números y underscores.

Un namespace que comience con backslash, entonces:

```
  <?php
  // ERROR
  namespace \App\CualquierCosa;
```

Es ilegal porque `"\App\CualquierCosa"` incumple la regla para nombrar un label, y por otro lado no puedes usar un FQNS como para declarar un namespace absoluto `\"App\CualquierCosa"`, porque los NS siempre son relativos con respecto a la ubicación donde los montes.

Pensemos que mi proyecto tiene la siguiente estructura de directorios y archivos

```
- lib
  - MiClase.php
   
- app
  - Kernel.php
```

Donde `MiClase.php`  contiene

```
<?php
namespace Lib;
class MiClase { ... }
```

Y Kernel.php contiene:

```
<?php
namespace App;
class Kernel { ... }
```

En mi `composer.json` podría indicar que el autoloader PSR-4 se mapea como

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
      "Lib\\": "lib/"
```

Y luego instanciar cada una como

```
      <?php

      new \App\Kernel();
```

y

```
      new \Lib\MiClase();
```

**Pero** también soy dueño de montar arbitrariamente

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
      "App\\Utils\\": "lib/"
```

Lo cual tendría como consecuencia que el FQNS de `MiClase` fuese `\App\Utils\MiClase`. Y desde `Kernel.php` podría instanciarla así o con el NS relativo:

```
      <?php
      namespace App;
      class Kernel { ... } 

      new \App\Utils\MiClase(...);

      new Utils\MiClase(...);
```

Por lo mismo una clase no puede arrogarse la autoridad de establecer taxativamente su namespace absoluto. Eso rompería de plano la lógica de resolución.

Ahora, para el caso donde no hay otro mapa explícito con el `composer.json`, desde el punto de montaje hacia adentro, la resolución es 1:1 con el sistema de archivos.

Dado que, por ejemplo `app` está montado en  `App`, no necesitas declarar otros mapas para usar el namespace `App\Controllers` dentro del directorio `app/Controllers`. Y a la inversa, si quisieras usar el namespace `App\Controladores` dentro de ese subdirectorio, no podrías hacerlo sin declarar explícitamente un mapa en el composer.

Por lo anterior, un namespace que empezara con slash, como en tu pregunta

```
<?php
namespace /test
```

No sólo es ilegal acorde a las reglas para un label, sino que implicaría una resolución absoluta en el sistema de archivos.

El error que estás viendo

```
    Call to undefined function foo()
```

Se debe a que olvidaste regenerar el autoloader. Si acaso hubieses ejecutado `composer dumpautoload`, te hubiera saltado en cambio

```
    PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected token "/"
```

Answer (score -1):

Esto sucede porque seguramente ha declarado espacios de nombres en su:

```
test.php;
```

Si elimina el espacio de nombres, dejará de indexar sus métodos bajo un espacio de nombres y permanecerán **públicos/globales**, no sé si esto está documentado en alguna parte… pero ya me había pasado.